# Google Api redirection with passport

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, passport.js

I have a google auth API in my app, can I somehow attach user data with redirect function? Or how can I see if the user logged in at my react app. 
For example here I'm sending username in my request field, but I don't know the way to access it...

```
router.get('/google/redirect', passport.authenticate('google'), (req, res) => {
     res.redirect('http://localhost:3100/login1/' + req.user.username);
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to request the authentication flow alike this:

```
router.get('/auth/login',
   (req, res, next) => {

        // Save the url of the user's current page so the app can redirect back to it after authorization
        if (req.query.return) {req.session.oauth2return = req.query.return;}
        next();
    },

    // Start OAuth 2 flow using Passport.js
    passport.authenticate('google', { scope: ['email', 'profile'] })
);
```

and then handle the post-back alike this:

```
// OAuth 2 callback url.
// Use this url to configure your OAuth client in the Google Developers console.
router.get('/auth/google/callback',

    // Finish OAuth 2 flow using Passport.js
    passport.authenticate('google'), (req, res) => {
        // Redirect back to the original page, if any
        const redirect = req.session.oauth2return || '/';
        delete req.session.oauth2return;
        res.redirect(redirect);
    }
);
```

while your `localhost` does not have any route-able IP, therefore you will never receive any post-back. hosting the script on-line (with a publicly route-able IP) is required to make it work "as expected".